# exclude multiple files from sourcing?

Tags: zsh, wildcards

I have `setopt extended_glob`, I want to exclude all files under `~/.config/zsh` that either start with `_` or filename is `completion.zsh` or `options.zsh`

I have this command:

```
for f (${${(%):-%x}:P:h:h}/**/([^_|^completion|^options])*.zsh) print $f
```

It does the job but above command also exclude `lazyload.zsh`, why above command exclude this pattern? I expected it will print out `lazyload.zsh`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just:

```
${${(%):-%x}:P:h:h}/**/(^(_|completion|options)*).zsh
```

`^` is the `extendedglob` negation operator.

Remember `[anything]` only ever matches one character¹.

`[a|b]` matches `a`, `|` or `b`, `[^a|b]` matches any character but `a`, `|` or `b`.

So your pattern excludes `lazyload.zsh` because `l` is in the list of character excluded by your `[^...]` single-character-matching operator.

---

<sup>¹ (in `zsh`; in some other shells, it may also match multi-character collating elements in some locales; zsh's `[...]` can also match bytes not forming parts of valid characters, YMMV with other shells)</sup>